# Getting through Capistrano configuration with Whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, whenever

I've set up a very simple method in my whenever gem's schedule.rb file

```
every 10.minutes do
   rake "update_models"
end
```

All I'm trying to accomplish now is configure Capistrano to automatically create the crontab by calling

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development
```

or

```
whenever -i
```

But i've been unsuccessful in getting through the lengthy configuration process. My Capfile has the following

```
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

My deploy.rb file has the following:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :update_crontab do
    run "cd /Users/affinities/Desktop/my_app && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development"
  end
end
```

I'm just trying to get the whenever gem to kick off it's schedule.rb file whenever I start up the server. Can someone give me a step by step to install the minimum amount of Capistrano required to do this? When I run "rails server" I want the crontab to be updated. I'm just trying to do it in the development environment right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, why do you think that capistrano should run your task on `rails server` command. Capistrano serves for deploy purposes and unrelated to your local `rails server` starting. By including

```
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

this line in `Capfile`, you tell capistrano to rewrite crontab on each **deploy**. It will also use environment, which is set in your `config/deploy/x.rb` in this variable `set :rails_env, 'environment'`. So the `require` line is all you need. And your `run` command(and task accordingly) makes no sense:

```
run "cd /Users/affinities/Desktop/my_app && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development"
```

Comment: Ok, I think that answers my question... rails server is not a deploy and so for a local server running Capistrano will basically do nothing, correct? I was able to solve my problem using Rufus-scheduler which worked like a charm!

Comment: @affinities23 you probably should read some articles about deployment. But in short words, capistrano is used to deliver your code from repository(say github) to remote server(s), and by requiring whenever/capistrano, after deploy it will also rewrite crontab on that remote server(s).